# Шапы и ботины

Tags: словообразование

[image]

Опустим сейчас неправильное употребление слова "одевать" — вопрос о другом. Суффикс "-к-" — вроде как уменьшительно-ласкательный: лапа-лапка, игла-иголка и т.д. Но существует ряд слов, которые без этого суффикса не существуют. Или изначально они все-таки существовали, а потом вышли из обихода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-разному. Суффикс -К- - очень многозначный, он может быть не только уменьшительным, он может выступать и просто в роли словообразовательного суффикса, не несущего в себе диминутива или какого-то подобного значения.
Часто без суффикса слово несет другое значение.
Хотя, конечно, утрата слова, некогда существовавшего без суффикса, - тоже вариант. 
Может быть и так, что суффикс в силу древности настолько сросся со словом, что вычленение его невозможно.

Без суффикса помимо "сосульки" и "шапки" никогда не употреблялись слова кошка, сосиска, водка и проч. - в их нынешнем значении.

Касательно "ботинка" - тут вообще спорный случай. Слово заимствовано, в языках- источниках (это может быть немецкий, английский или голландский) родственно слову "бот" (резиновая обувь), тоже заимствованному русским. Ну и как тут сформулировать роль суффикса в рамках заявленной темы?

> лапа-лапка, игла-иголка

рука-ручка, Ваня-Ванька, свеча-свечка, ложа-ложка, морковь-морковка, пеша-пешка?
Каждый случай надо рассматривать отдельно. Суффикс -К-  не так прост. Может означать всё что угодно, вплоть до уничижительности или фамильярности.